# Shell - making directories - Shell script has different outcome then Shell

Tags: macos, shell

I am trying to make a shell script that makes directories numbered from 01-13.

I use command mkdir -p test/file{01..13}

when I run command via shell script it names directories as 1,2,..,13 but when I use the command in shell itself, it names it correctly as 01,02,..,13. (see image below)

Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like your interactive session is using `zsh`, but you're running the shell script using `sh`. It's not surprising that you're seeing different behavior.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interactive shell is `zsh`, but you run the script with `sh`. To run your script with `zsh`, call `zsh soubor2.sh`.

Alternatively, and recommended, add a shebang line to your script: `#!/bin/zsh` and mark it executable with `chmod u+x soubor2.sh`. Then you can execute it with just `./soubor2.sh` and it will be executed with the right shell automatically.

Comment: Ah, running with zsh worked, thank you!